# Hooking up 50 amp box

Tags: electrical

I have a 200 amp meter base mounted on a wood 'pole' with a cross 2x10 on it  next to it i have a 200 disconnect that will eventually feed a 200 amp breaker box . But until that time can I run a direct  Burial 8/3 with ground from the 200 amp disconnectto a 50 amp plug in for a camper

Comment: Think you need full wire gauge for the 200 amps.  Breaker determines/protects the wire gauge after it, not before.  If the disconnect had a breaker in it and you place a 50 amp breaker there, then 8 gauge would be okay.

Comment: 8/3 UF is only 40A wire.  So you'd need a direct burial type other than UF, or switch it up to 6-6-6-6 aluminum or even better, 2-2-2-4.

Answer (score 5):

No, 8/3 is too costly and that does not provide breaker protection.

I would use 2-2-2-4 aluminum (cheaper and good for up to 90A, so room for expansion) to a 50A disconnect out at the RV stand. They sell "RV panels" that provide that + outlet + a 120V GFCI outlet (which I believe may be a Code requirement and you'll really want it anyway).

The disconnect serves the purpose of adapting the #2 aluminum to the 50A socket, as the socket might not be able to take #2 wire.  And also provides the required 50A breaker protection for a 50A socket.

You need to protect the #2 wire with a breaker <=90A, so I would use a 2-space panel with a 60A breaker in it.  The 60A is the smallest breaker that will directly take #2.